# Pure CSS and jQuery input caret/cursor

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to implement an input cursor with CSS and jQuery.

I got the idea after reading [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?17450-Emulating-a-terminal-like-caret-with-javascript-and-css) article that teaches how to do something like [this](http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html)

In order to provice squared passwords with jQuery (as a cross-browser solution to [-webkit-text-security: squared](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-security)).

The trick is made, by dealing with two inputs: a hidden one, and the one that actually shows the squares. 
The focus stays with the hidden field, so the `input cursor` it's lost. 
That's not very functional, as the user is not able to see where it's writing.

After some thinking I implemented the idea on an `input[type="text"]`. 
Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jviotti/knfma/) I wrote to see what I'm talking about.
If you write on the **`hidden`** field (well, its not hidden in the fiddle for experimantation purposes) the password input renders squares and a **`green cursor`**.

The squares are of the same size, however, their size variates on different browsers, causing the cursor to not move according the text.

```
Chrome:
```

[image: Chrome]

```
Firefox
```

[image: Firefox]

```
Opera
```

[image: Opera]

In the fiddle, I'm using a **fixed pixel value** to move the cursor right and left.

My fiddle works fine in Chrome, but FF and Opera both renders the square in different sizes.

- How can I predict the width that will take the rendered square?
- Is there a way to get the square width on each browser and move
  correctly the cursor?
- Is there a better approach to include the cursor?

Any help, ideas or anything would be really appreciated. I'm driving crazy with this.

**UPDATE:** Backspace funcionality does not even work in FF.

Comment: I personally think it is a bad idea to mess with the understood UI in this way.

Comment: Oh man, you're *still* working on this? Someone *really* wants this feature eh?

Comment: @bookcasey I think the same way as you.

Comment: @WesleyMurch hehe It was working, but now they want the cursor :)

Comment: Hope you're getting paid by the hour for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set the font-size for that input: http://jsfiddle.net/knfma/22/

```
input {
  display: block;   
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size:12px; // set this and see if works cross browser
}                 // tested on chrome and ff
```

Comment: But it proportionally reduces the width in all browser. We're back when we started.